# toString().length on a number with zeros and only zeros always returns 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, user-interface, frontend

I'm working on a page that accepts 4 digits (exactly 4 digits) pin from users. Something like this.

```
<input type="number" ng-model="passCode" class="form-control" onpaste="return false" id="passCodeField"  ng-disabled="!enablePassCode" ng-change="onInputPasscode()" ng-keypress="onKeyPressPasscode($event)"/>
```

onKeyPressPasscode function

```
$scope.onKeyPressPasscode = function($event) {
    if(isNaN(String.fromCharCode($event.which || $event.keyCode))){
        $event.preventDefault();
     }
}
```

onInputPasscode() function :

```
$scope.onInputPasscode = function() {
    if ($scope.passCode.toString().length > 4){
        $scope.passCode = $scope.passcode;
    }
    if($scope.passCode.toString().length == 4) {
         $scope.passcode = $scope.passCode;
         $scope.disableContinue = false;
         session.put('pinFlow',true);
    } else {
         console.log("current length - " + $scope.passCode);
         $scope.disableContinue = true;
         session.put('pinFlow',false);
    }

}
```

This is failing when the input is all zeros. i.e current length is not getting updated hence the user is allowed input as many zeros as he wants. How do I take 4 digit zeros as input and still meet the checks that I have?

[image: debugging image]

This is in angular 1.5.8v. And I'm not an expert in `AngularJS`. So any help would be appreciated. Also, please let me know if need any other info. I'll update the answer accordingly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Imo you shouldn't use `input type=number` for a PIN entry field since PINs don't have the type `number`. Instead, use `input type=text` or probably even better, `input type=password`. Also, I wouldn't listen to `keypress` - instead use the `input` event.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to do this with a an input with `type` set to `number`.
When user enters a number `0001`, that's actually `1`.
Things like PINs should be handled with `type` set to `text`.
You can then use a regex for validation.

To allow exactly four digits, no more and no less, use the following regex:

```
^\d{4,4}$
```

From JavaScript, use this regex to test a string, like the following:

```
/^\d{4,4}$/.test('1234')
// => true

/^\d{4,4}$/.test('123456')
// => false

/^\d{4,4}$/.test('12')
// => false
```

Comment: leading zeroes are part of the [*valid floating point number*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#valid-floating-point-number)  scheme and should be retained in the `value` of an input[type="number"]. If a browser doesn't do it, it is buggy. `HTMLInput.value` always return a string, if you want the numeric equivalent, you can access it through `input.valueAsNumber`.

Comment: `\d{4}` seems simpler than `\d{4,4}`

Answer (score 1):

The cause of your problem is that if you PIN Scheme allows for leadings zeros, `number` is not the ideal type for this (because in numbers, leading zeros can be omitted without changing meaning).

Instead, use `input type=text` or probably even better, `input type=password`. Also, I wouldn't listen to `keypress` - instead use the `input` event.